# Understanding a step in a proof: Complement of an uncountable set is countable??

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I refer to Schilling (*Measures, Integrals and Martingales*, 2005, 1st edition, pp. 15-16).

Usual definition of $\sigma$-algebra:

[image]

Claim:

[image]

Proof:

[image]

I've underlined in red the step I have trouble understanding.

Is it saying that $A_{j_0}$ is uncountable implies $A_{j_0}^c$ must be countable? Is this claim generally true? (And if not, what does the author mean here?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A_{j_0}$ is a member of $A$ so by definition it is either countable or its complement is. It's not true in general that the complement of an uncountable set is countable, consider for instance $[0,\infty)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

The collection $\mathcal A$ in the claim is defined as containing those subsets of $X$ for which $\#A\leqslant\#\mathbb N$ or $\#A^c\leqslant\#\mathbb N$. $A_{j_0}\in\mathcal A$, so by definition, either $\#A_{j_0}\leqslant\#\mathbb N$ or $\#A^c_{j_0}\leqslant\#\mathbb N$. In $\Sigma_3$ (second case), $A_{j_0}\not\leqslant\#\mathbb N$, so it must be the case that $A^c_{j_0}\leqslant\#\mathbb N$.